# python list comprehension return names based on letter

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I have a `DataFrame`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(['A','B','C'], columns = ['Letters'])
```

I have a list with `names`:

```
names = ['George All', 'George Ball','George Ago','George Call']
```

How do I create a new column in my `DataFrame` that contains the list of names that have a last name that start with the `Letters` column.

For example:

```
Letters  Names
A        ['George All','George Ago']
B        George Ball
C        George Call
```

This is what I have right now:

```
df['Names'] = [name for name in names if (name.split()[1][0] == df['Letters'])]
```

Comment: yea, i added what I have

Comment: Again, don't need say "thanks".

Comment: It's usually a better idea to use lists everywhere, even when there is only one item

Comment: @JohnLaRooy will a dictionary be better than what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: @IamnotGeorge, see my answer. You can use a dict to make the algorithm O(n)

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want a `DataFrame` - eg: what are you going to do that warrants such a strange looking structure?

Comment: @JonClements I am using selenium to click a link that takes me to all 'A' names then I will click through each 'A' name to scrape data. so on so forth. I am open to suggestions on how to make it more efficient.

Comment: @IamnotGeorge doesn't sound like you want dataframes then - just stick with a `dict`

Comment: @JonClements okay gotcha

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
>>> df['Names'] = [[n for n in names if n.split()[1][0] == x] for x in df['Letters']]
>>> df
  Letters                     Names
0       A  [George All, George Ago]
1       B             [George Ball]
2       C             [George Call]

[3 rows x 2 columns]
```

You could do this more efficiently (important if `names` is a large list) by grouping all the names by first letter beforehand.

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for item in names:
...     d[item.split()[1][0]].append(item)
... 
>>> df['Names'] = [d[x] for x in df['Letters']]
>>> df
  Letters                     Names
0       A  [George All, George Ago]
1       B             [George Ball]
2       C             [George Call]
```

Comment: Or even ``for name in names: d.setdefault(name.split()[1][0], []).append(name)`` if you want to avoid importing ``defaultdict``.